# for row in df.CUSTOMER_CONTENTION_TEXT.values: Where can i find it with my excel file

Tags: python, word-cloud

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('ggplot')

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

df = pd.read_excel(r'crawling.xlsx')

text = ''
for row in df.CUSTOMER_CONTENTION_TEXT.values:
    text = text + row.value() + ' '

wc = WordCloud(max_words=2000,
               stopwords=STOPWORDS, font_path=r'NanumBarunGothic.otf')
# generate word cloud
wc.generate(text)

# store to file
wc.to_file(r'first.png')

# show
plt.imshow(wc)
plt.axis("off")
plt.figure()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I got a code from github [https://gist.github.com/pybokeh/de5475328fb2bbb33cb7]
python_wordcloud_from_excel.ipynb

**for row in df.CUSTOMER_CONTENTION_TEXT.values:**

I can not understand. Can you explain this? I want to fix this code and use it, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide some background information on what you are trying to acheive with the code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I want to create a word cloud from the data contained in my excel file. So I changed the file path and fixed the code in question with several functions in df, but couldn't find any code to replace it. thank you for reading

Comment: I am not certain what you expect as an answer. Do you need an explaination for what the for loop does?

Comment: I found that there is no function like CUSTOMER_CONTENTION_TEXT in the DataFrame. How did the owner of the original code execute it?

Comment: This is not a function, it's an attribute. It's a way to access columns in the dataframe. It's not the right way to access columns if you ask me because it's confusing. In pandas dataframes you can access a column via `df.column_name` or `df['column_name']`

Answer (score 0):

It is the first row, column value in Excel.